# Microsoft Sql Server 2005 issue

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

If I try to run the application i am getting this error.

```
Connection Failed:
SQL State: '01000'
SQL Server: Error: 2
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBMSLPCN]ConnectionOpen (Connect())
Connection Failed:
SQL State: '08001'
SQL Server Error: 17
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBMSLPCN]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
```

The applciation was working fine, untill I replaced my motherboard.

I want my db, how can I get backup of my db or how to resolve the issue to connect to microsoft sql server 2005.

Any solution welcome.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me also , Here's how i fixed that:

Under SQL Server Configuration Manager, TCP/IP was already enabled all along under `SQL Server 2005 Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLEXPRESS` and `SQL Native Client Configuration > Client Protocols.` Named Pipes was already enabled in the latter.

I enabled it in the former, but that didn't seem to help (same error messages). Finally, I switched the ODBC source to use the "SQL Native Client" driver instead of the "SQL Server" driver, and that finally DID work.

Reference : https://serverfault.com/questions/82007/how-do-i-get-this-sql-server-odbc-connection-working

Comment: I switched the ODBC source to use the "SQL Native Client" driver instead of the "SQL Server" driver?? Where do I specify this or what to do to change that. can I know ?

Comment: @Ram You might get help here http://serverfault.com/questions/82007/how-do-i-get-this-sql-server-odbc-connection-working

Comment: Finally, I switched the ODBC source to use the "SQL Native Client" driver instead of the "SQL Server" driver??I am new to sql. This option were it will be available ?? Can you be more specific where i can find this option?

Comment: @Ram Answer no.1 Comment no.1